# In postgresql, what's the difference a "database" and a "relation"? ('error relation x does not exist', 'error database x already exists')

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relation

I see the juxtaposition of these two errors and, given the dearth of Google search results, had to ask. What is the difference and what do I need to be doing here?

```
deploy=# GRANT SELECT ON angel_research_production TO angel_research;
ERROR:  relation "angel_research_production" does not exist
deploy=# create database angel_research_production;
ERROR:  database "angel_research_production" already exists
```

My guess is that I need to be doing this grant select business from some other user...

So I run this on postgres (dbroot) and get this:

```
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON angel_research_production TO angel_research;
ERROR:  relation "angel_research_production" does not exist
```

So it does exist as a database, but not as a relation. How might I rectify this and what are the underlying issues here? I'm a little overwhelmed. Thanks

Comment: I think it's expecting a table or a schema, not a database..

Comment: What's with the "death" of Google search results? Curious to know...

Comment: dearth, not death. dearth means a 'lack of'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My guess is that you really want to recursively `GRANT` the `SELECT` right to every relation (table and view) within the database `angel_research_production`. Correct?

### How to grant on all tables in a database

If so, in PostgreSQL 9.0 and above you have:

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...]
         | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

from the [manual for GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html). Note the `ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA` clause. Usage:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO angel_research;
```

If all your user-defined objects are in the `public` [schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) (see below) that'll do the trick.

In prior versions there is no such feature, but [user defined functions exist as workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599533/postgresql-8-4-grant-dml-privileges-on-all-tables-to-a-role).

Pg 9.0 also has [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), which changes the *default* privileges assigned to *newly created* objects. It does not affect existing objects.

### What does the error message mean?

As noted by TokenMacGuy, a relation is a table or view, not a database.

```
GRANT SELECT ON angel_research_production TO angel_research;
```

can be thought of as shorthand for:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE angel_research_production TO angel_research
                ^^^^^
```

and that table(relation) doesn't exist, so you're getting the error reported above.

In the [manual for GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) or the `psql` `\h GRANT` output you'll see:

```
GRANT { { CREATE | CONNECT | TEMPORARY | TEMP } [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON DATABASE database_name [, ...]
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

This shows that the privileges you can `GRANT` to a database are `CREATE`, `CONNECT` and `TEMPORARY`. There is no `SELECT` right on a database.

### Relations? Schema? Huh?

There are four levels of organisation in Pg:

- [Cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html) - controlled by the postmaster, accepts connections on a given IP/port combo, contains one or more *databases* including the built-in `template0`, `template1` and `postgres` databases. Controlled by `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`. Your DB cluster is often created for you by an installer or package. Not to be confused with the normal meaning of cluster as a [compute cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) or the general [english language meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster).
- [Database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-createdb.html) - contains one or more *schemata* or *schemas*. You connect to a specific database when connecting to Pg.
- [Schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) - contains *objects* including *relations*. If you don't specify otherwise, anything user-created goes into the `public` schema. Queries can reference objects in multiple schema explicitly or, via [search_path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH), implicitly.
- [Objects](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-others.html) - Somewhat PostgreSQL specific, anything (including a relation) that exists in a schema.

  - Relations - Things that look and behave like tables, like [views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-views.html) and [tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-basics.html)
  - Other objects also reside in schemas, like functions, casts, indexes, sequences, operators, aggregates, etc.

Comment: @putin2012 Learning via the Internet is often the best way, you just have to pick your resources well. I'd strongly advise you to read the PostgreSQL documentation cover-to-cover, it'll teach you a lot about SQL and databases in general.

Comment: that last section -- 

Answer (score 10):

a relation is a table (or something that looks like one, eg a view), that is, it is a collection of rows, all with the same fields, and given some name to reference them by.

A database is a collection of relations and other entities (like triggers, functions and rules) that are kept together in some logical grouping.

Comment: +1 Note that this is also normal relational database nomenclature; these terms aren't specific to PostgreSQL.

Comment: There's also an intermediate level, a schema. Really a database is a collection of schemata, and a schema is a collection of relations (tables+views) and - in PostgreSQL - other objects like user-defined functions, definitions for casts, operators, aggregates, etc. In Pg, the `public` schema contains all user objects not explicitly placed elsewhere, the `pg_catalog` schema contains all the system objects, and there's also the `information_schema` schema and some other `pg_` system schema.

Comment: Looking back years later, this is the conceptual answer to my question, while the other was the technical answer. Thanks