# postgres 8.4 - grant privileges

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

How can I grant privileges of all tables of a certain schema to a certain role in **Postgres8.4**?

In Postgres9.x, I can just do this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO myRole
```

It seems like Postgres8.4 doesn't support the **ALL TABLE** keyword. Is there an alternative to achieving the same result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL 8.4 grant DML privileges on all tables to a role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599533/postgresql-8-4-grant-dml-privileges-on-all-tables-to-a-role)

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600950/582049) you can use the following syntax:

```
select 'GRANT ALL ON ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name ||' to my_group;' 
from information_schema.tables 
where 
    table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and 
    table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```